# Microsoft Graph API Road Map

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can't seem to find anything more than the changelog, does anyone know if there's a roadmap for planned functionality?

Notably, we're looking to have our employees enroll in MFA through a custom app calling the Graph API and add their mobile number, other email, and authenticator. I found a confirmation that this would be available from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20249953-powershell-and-graph-api-support-for-managing-mult) but there hasn't been any update for nearly two years.

Answer (score 1):

There is no roadmap for Microsoft Graph currently. We announce new features into preview throughout the year with two major moments at Build and Ignite conferences. You can keep up with those announcements at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/.

We do have a Microsoft Graph UserVoice https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/ where you can request and see others requests. Our PMs will actually change the status of features that are in development. This will give you a subset of the things we're working on that relate to public requests.

As you mention , our Change log will be the way to track new things on the API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog.

We also have a monthly Community Call online that we announce things that is the first tuesday of every month. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/events . Existing events are blogged about and also available here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/gallery/?filterBy=Podcasts,Videos

Comment: This is so horrible.  Microsoft Graph truly is horrendous in almost every way, and the total lack of any kind of roadmap is a perfect example

Answer (score 0):

The roadmap for the Graph API can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Microsoft%20Graph